# Unable to run "npm run start" command while opening React app server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
(node:12448) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please
use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

I am getting this error while I am trying to run `npm run start` command in VS Code to open React app server. I am expecting to open my server successfully. Suddenly, this problem arises.

Comment: try npm run start

Comment: 1. It's just a warning. 2. Have you tried doing what it suggests?

Comment: @justanotherguy I had edited my question, I already tried npm run start.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I tried to solve but didn't get the exact solution.

Comment: _What_ did you try, and what happened? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` with the below, as said by the error.

```js
setupMiddlewares
```

This may remove the `DeprecationWarning`.

Comment: That _is_ the command they're running. And how and where exactly should they be making a replacement?

Comment: You reckon? If they're using e.g. CRA it won't actually appear in their codebase. And the value between the two options is different, it's not just a case of changing the name.